# Logic for translating text using Google Docs script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Stemming from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209778/passing-information-to-server-side-function-in-a-google-docs-add-on), I'm creating an Add On for Google Docs which takes the body of a document and translates it as a new page in the same doc. I have the script running and it's translating correctly, but I'm having trouble with the logic to keep the formatting.

**[This post from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575863/how-do-i-format-text-i-am-copying-from-google-document-in-google-app-script/17577431#17577431)** works well when copying elements in the same language. But, the `LanguageApp` in Google requires a `string` to translate.

I simplified the script linked above to copy a document within itself:

```
function simpleTranslate() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  Logger.log(body.getAttributes());
  var elements = body.getNumChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i<elements; ++i) {
    var element = body.getChild(i).copy();

    var type = element.getType();
    if(type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      // This block copies formatting correctly
      // Pastes English and Spanish into the doc (see img 1).
      body.appendParagraph(element);
      var spn = LanguageApp.translate(element.getText(), 'en', 'es');
      body.appendParagraph(spn);

      // This block pastes Spanish only with no formatting (see img 2)
      // This block is normally commented out when the script runs for testing
      var spn = LanguageApp.translate(element.getText(), 'en', 'es');
      body.appendParagraph(spn)
    }
  }
}
```

**Img1** - text formats correctly, pastes both English and Spanish

[Img1 http://www.brianbennett.org/images/coderesult1.png](http://www.brianbennett.org/images/coderesult1.png)

**Img2** - removing the English append, Spanish still translates but loses formatting because of `string` requirement.

[Img2 http://www.brianbennett.org/images/coderesult2.png](http://www.brianbennett.org/images/coderesult2.png)

I would like help with the logic within the function. I'm thinking the only way to do this - because of the `string` requirement - is to go line by line, copying the English, translating on a new line, then removing the English. **Is there a better way to translate the text and keep the formatting?**

Comment: Could you post examples (images would do) showing the problem? Nudge - if [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575863/how-do-i-format-text-i-am-copying-from-google-document-in-google-app-script/17577431#17577431) helped, why not upvote it?

Comment: At school right now, so I can't post images...will do so tonight. And I thought I'd already upvoted. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Mogsdad Just updated with cleaner code and some images showing the input and result from running the script under both circumstances.

Comment: Cool - I'll have a look this evening, unless someone else figures it out first!

Answer (score 1):

Since machine translation is not a word-for-word operation, it's reasonable to assume that formatting for each translated paragraph will be homogeneous (i.e. the whole paragraph will have the same formatting).

Given that, you can copy *most* of the format of a paragraph using [`Paragraph.getAttributes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getAttributes()), then apply them to the new paragraph with [`Paragraph.setAttributes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setAttributes(Object)).

Something like:

```
...
if(type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
  // get formatting attributes
  var attributes = element.getAttributes();      

  var spn = LanguageApp.translate(element.getText(), 'en', 'es');
  var newParagraph = body.appendParagraph(spn);

  // Copy format to translated paragraph
  newParagraph.setAttributes(attributes)
}
...
```

Comment: I hadn't tried setting attributes with a second variable - I had been chaining it onto `body.appendParagraph(spn)` with mixed results. I'll play around some more during my planning hour today and see what ends up working.

Comment: It's been a while since I messed around with these functions; I also remember them being finicky. You may need to examine the returned attributes looking for font styles, then set them explicitly.

Comment: I think it's the string being passed that doesn't carry the attributes. It's not a big deal in the long run. I don't have a *ton* of formatting to redo, so I'm not going to go through and read it line by line. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.